# Order of messages in SingalR - how to ensure it

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, real-time

I'm using SingalR in an application that sends alot messages in a short period of time.
let's say i have client A and client B.
Client A just sends messages and client B just listening to messages.
Client A sends the following messages in the following order: A->B->C->D

What i'm seeing is that Client B sometimes receives the messages in a different order, for example: B->A->C->D

It is important for maintain the same order i sent the messages.
I've looked online and i found people saying i should use **async-await** on the function on the hub that handles those messages.

```
public async Task hubMethod(msgObject msg)
{
   await Clients.All.message(msg);
}
```

I'm not sure how that helps since each time i make a call from client A , singalR should create a new instance of the hub. 
The only thing it does is wait for the singalR that it finished doing all it can do on the server in order to send the message to the other client and notifies it to client A.

So my question is this - is there a **singalR** or asp.net mechanism that make sure i receive the messages in the correct order on the other client or do i need to write my own mechanism (server or client) that reorders the messages if they are out of order - and if so, is there a library that already does it?

Comment: How are you trying to figure out the order in which messages are being sent?

Comment: If i were to write my own infrastructure that handles the order of the messages being sent - the simplest solution is to number the messages sent from client A - and along the way either at client B or the server - reorder them if they arrive at the wrong order.
But what i want to know if singalR or any of the libraries it uses (asp.net) are able to do it already without me writing the code

Comment: I don't think SignalR has any inbuilt mechanism for anyone to know the order in which messages were generated by default, particularly if you are generating a large number in a short time. As Sandman suggests, adding a counter or a timestamp could be a way to ensure correct ordering if you are not generating millions of messages per second. You may also need to factor in non-receipt of some messages, depending on your ability to guarantee delivery. There's no point re-ordering on the server, as other clients may still receive the messages out of order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own mechanism. SignalR in client B has no way to know in which order the clients messages were sent by client A because there is many things that could delay a specific message arrival, like network delay, the only thing SignalR can guarantee is the order in which the messages arrived.

If you really need to know the original order of the messages you could put a count inside the message and let client B sort them out. However i suggest you try another approach, because guaranteeing the order of delivery is not a easy task.